# Problema con trying to get property ' ' of non object

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un metodo que retorna un array ordenado de la siguiente manera:

```
$propertyData = [
    'id'=>$property->id,
    'id_ubicacion'=>$property->id_ubicacion,
    'id_tipo_inmueble'=>$property->id_tipo_inmueble,
    'nomenclatura'=>$property->nomenclatura,
    'area'=>$property->area,
    'descripcion'=>$property->descripcion,
    'coeficiente'=>$property->coeficiente,
    'chip_catastral'=>$property->chip_catastral,
    'matricula_inmobiliaria'=>$property->matricula_inmobiliaria,
    'estado'=>$property->estado,
    'updated_at'=>$property->updated_at,
    'created_at'=>$property->created_at,
    'people' => $people
];
```

Cuando intento acceder a alguno de sus datos (esto mediante `$propertyData->nomenclatura` (o cualquier otro dato dentro del array)) me retorna `Trying to get property 'nomenclatura' of non-object`

Cabe resaltar que el problema no es que los datos estén vacíos, cuando llamo `$propertyData` funciona perfectamente y me lista todos los datos.

Comment: como asignaste el valor a `$property`?

Comment: Mediante otro array que obtengo a la base de datos, cuando uso ese array funciona a la perfección

Comment: por favor agrega el código relevante a la pregunta. Si dices que `$property` es un array, debes acceder a los elementos de esta forma `$property['id']`, pues `$property->id` solo funciona para objetos

Comment: Con tu comentario solucionaste mi problema, tienes razón, me equivoque y $property no es un array si no un objeto, pero tenia la duda de como acceder a los datos de $propertyData, gracias

Comment: Ah! ok, había leído mal y no ví que era sobre `$propertyData` el error. Puedes escribir una respuesta con cual era el problema y cómo lo solucionaste, así también le puede servir a otros que tengan el mismo problema

Comment: Disculpa @porloscerrosΨ , tengo otra duda, sucede que `$property` tiene otros objetos dentro, si los incluyo en el array, como los llamaria dentro de `$propertyData` (obvio despues de incluirlos en este array)? Se me ocurrio algo como `$propertyData[nombreObjeto->atributoObjeto]`, seria así?

Comment: Bueno, depende de como los incluyes, de como o de que tipo son esos objetos, y que es lo que quieres lograr con eso. Sin eso información, solo puede hacer suposiciones, me imagino algo así `$objeto = $propertyData['objeto']; $atributo = $objeto->atributoObjeto;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No puedes acceder aun array con las sintaxis de flecha (`->`) que son propias de los objetos, de ahí que te arroje el error:

> Trying to get property 'nomenclatura' of non-object

Puedes acceder con los corchetes (`[]`) al array:

```
$propertyData = [
    'id'=>$property->id,
    'id_ubicacion'=>$property->id_ubicacion,
    'id_tipo_inmueble'=>$property->id_tipo_inmueble,
    'nomenclatura'=>$property->nomenclatura,
    'area'=>$property->area,
    'descripcion'=>$property->descripcion,
    'coeficiente'=>$property->coeficiente,
    'chip_catastral'=>$property->chip_catastral,
    'matricula_inmobiliaria'=>$property->matricula_inmobiliaria,
    'estado'=>$property->estado,
    'updated_at'=>$property->updated_at,
    'created_at'=>$property->created_at,
    'people' => $people
];

//echo $propertyData['key_a_acceder']
echo $propertyData['nomenclatura'];
```

Otra opción es forzar la conversión del array a un objeto `stdClass`, ten encuenta que esto solo afecta al primer nivel del array, es decir si tienen objetos u otros arrays dentro estos no son afectados:

```
// con (object) convertimos a objeto
$propertyData = (object) [
    'id'=>$property->id,
    'id_ubicacion'=>$property->id_ubicacion,
    'id_tipo_inmueble'=>$property->id_tipo_inmueble,
    'nomenclatura'=>$property->nomenclatura,
    'area'=>$property->area,
    'descripcion'=>$property->descripcion,
    'coeficiente'=>$property->coeficiente,
    'chip_catastral'=>$property->chip_catastral,
    'matricula_inmobiliaria'=>$property->matricula_inmobiliaria,
    'estado'=>$property->estado,
    'updated_at'=>$property->updated_at,
    'created_at'=>$property->created_at,
    'people' => $people
];

//echo $propertyData->propiedad_a_acceder
echo $propertyData->nomenclatura;
```

---

### Algunos casos de acceso frecuentes

Dependiento del tipo de dato que intentes acceder necesitas utilizar una nomenclatura u otra, veamos un ejemlo con un array convertido a objeto stdClass y un array:

```
<?php
// con un objeto
$dataStdClass = (object) [
    'array'=> array('primero' => 'array 1', 'segndo' => 'array 2'),
    'objeto'=> (object) ['primero' => 'property 1', 'segundo' => 'property 2'],
    'scalar'=> 'dato escalar'
];

// primero '->' para acceder a la propiedad objeto y luego '[]' para acceder a la clave dentro del array de segundo nivel
echo $dataStdClass->array['primero']; // array 1
// primero '->' para acceder a la propiedad objeto y otra vez '->' para aceder a la propiedad del objeto de segundo nivel
echo $dataStdClass->objeto->primero; //property 1
// para '->' acceder una propiedad scalar del objeto
echo $dataStdClass->scalar; //dato escalar


// con un array
$dataArray = [
    'array'=> array('primero' => 'array 1', 'segndo' => 'array 2'),
    'objeto'=> (object) ['primero' => 'property 1', 'segundo' => 'property 2'],
    'scalar'=> 'dato escalar'
];

// primero '[]' para acceder a la clave del array y luego '[]' para acceder a la clave dentro del array de segundo nivel
echo $dataArray['array']['primero']; // array 1
// primero '[]' para acceder a la clave del array y luego '->' para aceder a la propiedad del objeto de segundo nivel
echo $dataArray['objeto']->primero; //property 1
// para '[]' acceder una clave scalar del array
echo $dataArray['scalar']; //dato escalar
```

### Referencias:

- [Datos primitivos PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.intro.php)
- [Conversión a objeto](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.object.php)
- [Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php)